# How to use an asterisk in list items instead of a bullet

Tags: html, css

I want to use "*" in one of the bullet items. I have used Pseudo class to one of the element. But i see some blank space before "text2" in below example to the pseudo `li` element

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li.str:before {
  content: "*";
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li class="str">text2</li>
</ul>
```

Could you please help me here

Answer (score 10):

Set your li tags in position relative and your pseudo-element in position absolute :

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
li.str:before {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li class="str">text2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Im Looking for a responsive page, so any chance we can achieve using position relative?

Comment: Just use ems instead of pixels for better responsivity.

Comment: @Sumanth : I don't know what you try to achieve but position absolute should not bother you in a responsive layout. At worst you can  change it in a media query.

Comment: Yea, We can achieve using absolute, but  you need to lot of coding when we target every pixel and when content wraps in lower breakpoint, So im Wondering if we can achieve using relative with minimal coding

Comment: I tried quickly and can't find an answer. About absolute positioning, it will always be absolute to the relative parent, so you don't need to change it unless you don't have the space anymore to fit what you want, but the problem remains if you use position relative. (i'm not sure if I'm clear ... I hope so :p).

Answer (score 1):

use an image

```
http://jsbin.com/vitumerahe/edit?html,css,output
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mpLQ5__-L-I/VJRpKS3KtGI/AAAAAAAAMXA/YfYAJql--mU/s1600/star.png")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text2</li>
  </ul>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

As Mentioned by others you can use List. If you want to show in between words, you can use html code before the text like below

```
&#42;
```

Output

* Text1

* Text2

* Text3

And so on...

Comment: This approach is insufficient because lists affect line wrapping too.